# ¿Por que no funciona response.sendRedirect?

Tags: jsp

Me gustaría saber por que la instrucción `response.sendRedirect("URL")` no me funciona, a continuación os dejo el código, muchas gracias.

```
Conexion c = new Conexion();
Usuario usu = new Usuario(c,c.crearConexion());
boolean resultado = usu.verificarCredenciales(request.getParameter("usuario"),request.getParameter("password"));
if(resultado){
    session.setAttribute("usuario",request.getParameter("usuario"));        
    response.sendRedirect("conectado_controlador.jsp");

} else {
    if(session.getAttribute("usuario") != null){
        response.sendRedirect("conectado_controlador.jsp");
    } else {
         response.sendRedirect("index_controlador.jsp");
    }

}
```

He probado a usar rutas relativas y absolutas y nada.

Comment: Que rutas has probado para hacerlo?

Comment: que mensaje de error aparece? cual es el contexto de la aplicacion? cual es la url completa a la que deberia dirigir?

Comment: no me aperece ningún mensaje de error, las rutas que estoy usando son con respecto al index ya que estoy usando mvc, ahora investigando la página que me genera en blanco, cuando en el navegador pulse sobre ver codigo fuente de la página me aparecen 8 lineas en blanco, ¿creen que puede afectar eso?he probado a quitar los espacios en blanco antes y despues de cada <%%> pero sigue igual

Comment: lo curioso del asunto es que usando la etiqueta forward o el método forward si me redirecciona y la misma ruta en una me redirecciona y en otro no !!!

Comment: claro que tiene que aparecer un mensaje de error, como minimo un http 404 en el browser. El problema es que al hacer el redirect no estas especificando el contexto de la aplicacion

Comment: el contexto? me lo podrias explicar ? soy en esto de jsp, para aclararos un poco antes de hacer el redirect vengo de un include con <jsp:include>, he estado investigando y si uso este redirect request.getRequestDispathcer("conectado_controlador.jsp").forward(request, response) si me funciona, muchas gracias por contestarme @Klaimmore

Answer (score 2):

Supongamos que tenemos 2 paginas en la ruta raiz de nuestra aplicacion:

- index.jsp
- otro.jsp

`index.jsp` tiene el siguiente contenido:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="IndexServlet/requests?url=relativa">URL relativa</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="IndexServlet/requests?url=relativa-slash">URL relativa con slash</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="IndexServlet/requests?url=contexto">URL con contexto</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="IndexServlet/requests?url=absoluta">URL absoluta</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

La configuracion de servlet en `web.xml` tiene:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>IndexServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>jsp.ejemplo.IndexServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>IndexServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/IndexServlet/requests</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Y por ultimo el servlet `IndexServlet` tiene el siguiente metodo para responder a solicitudes `GET`:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    String url = request.getParameter("url");

    if(url.equals("relativa")) {
        response.sendRedirect("otro.jsp");
    } else if(url.equals("relativa-slash")) {
        response.sendRedirect("/otro.jsp");
    } else if(url.equals("contexto")) {
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/otro.jsp");
    } else if(url.equals("absoluta")){
        response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:7001/jsp-app/otro.jsp");
    } else {
        response.sendError(500, "parametro url no valido");
    }
}
```

El resultado de navegar por los distintos links sera:

- URL relativa: HTTP 404. El browser intenta acceder a la url

  ```
  "http://<Servidor>/jsp-app/IndexServlet/otra.jsp"
  ```
- URL relativa con slash: HTTP 404. El browser intenta acceder a la url

  ```
  "http://<Servidor>/otra.jsp"
  ```
- URL con contexto: OK. `request.getContextPath()` retorna el contexto de la aplicacion `/jsp-app` y por consiguiente el redirect es instruido a enviar a la url relativa

  ```
  "http://<Servidor>/jsp-app/otra.jsp"
  ```
- URL absoluta: OK. La url absoluta completa es enviada al redirect, por lo que no se traduce al ser enviada al browser

  ```
  "http://<Servidor>/jsp-app/otra.jsp"
  ```

---

El contexto de la aplicacion depende del servidor de aplicaciones utilizado, en weblogic por ejemplo se define en `weblogic.xml` como:

```
<context-root>/jsp-app</context-root>
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta, veo que eres un experto en este tema , te importaria darme algun correo para ponerme en contacto contigo y seguir hablando sobre este tema al respecto, si no es mucha molestia ?de lo contrario muchas gracias y gracias por tu tiempo

Answer (score 0):

No las toma porque hace falta poner bien la ruta

```
response.sendRedirect("/NombreDelProyecto/conectado_controlador.jsp");
```